# How to composite animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

i tried my best to search the answer on web, but i couldnt seem to find anything helpful.

so i finished building my animation scene. i also made a few render layer for compositing, one for blur effects, 1 for speed vectors, etc. now i want to render it into an animation. i checked the composite checkbox in the postprocessing tab, and hit animation button to render it. then it renders all the render layers one by one, and combine it into the composited results. but then it stops rendering so i only got 1 frame.

i read a thread here that said i should delete the render layers so blender will render it directly into a composited result, but in the composite node settings i need the render layer so i can get different effects for different objects.

how do i render the frames into PNGs file that is already composited? im sorry if my question confuse you, please ask me for more detail. any help is fully appreciated

Comment: Is the rendering ok without postprocessing? Have you checked the frame range? Have you defined an output directory?

Comment: Please post images of your render settings and nodes

Comment: @lemon yeah i didnt connect an output directory node on the tree settings. Apprently i need one to save the compositing results. Thanks!